# Input text validation based on drop-down list selection

Tags: validation, jsf-2

How can I validate an input text box based on a selection from the drop-down list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could pass the selected value of the dropdown as an attribute of the input component so that the validator can grab it.

E.g.

```
<h:selectOneMenu binding="#{menu}" value="#{bean.item}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.items}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:inputText value="#{bean.input}">
    <f:attribute name="item" value="#{menu.value}" />
    <f:validator validatorId="inputValidator" />
</h:inputText>
```

with

```
@FacesValidator("inputValidator")
public class InputValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        Object item = component.getAttributes().get("item");
        // ...
    }

}
```

Note that the ordering of the components matters. JSF processes [`UIInput`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) components in the order they appear in the view. If the dropdown component is placed *after* the input text component, then you need to pass `#{menu.submittedValue}` as attribute, but at that point the value is not converted yet. You could if necessary workaround with a `<h:inputHidden>` which is placed after the both components and put the validator in there.

Comment: Thanks, BalusC. It worked!!
Wish I could do +50 for your solution. You rock!