# What is component binding in JSF? When it is preferred to be used?

Tags: jsf, binding, components

I have read about component binding with `binding` attribute in following questions:

- [JSF component binding - some confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929518/jsf-component-binding-some-confusion)
- [component binding vs findComponent() - when to use which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474004/component-binding-vs-findcomponent-when-to-use-which/12477407#comment16811683_12477407)

I understand that it binds the UI component behind the JSF tag in the view to an `UIComponent` property in the backing bean. However, I am confused what the use of component binding is and when we should use it. Can someone explain it in a more simpler way and give some practical examples?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You should use it if you want to have access to the *entire* `UIComponent` instead of just only its value. For example, to access some methods which can't be invoked/bound in the view. This is answered in the 1st question you found: [JSF component binding - some confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929518/jsf-component-binding-some-confusion)

The 2nd question which you found, [component binding vs findComponent() - when to use which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474004/component-binding-vs-findcomponent-when-to-use-which/12477407), merely answers *"`binding` versus `findComponent()`"*, it does not answer *"`binding` versus `value`"* at all as you seem to think. Please don't get confused by this. *`value`* would obviously win over *`binding`*.

In real world code, component binding to the backing bean is often only used whenever the developer needs to manipulate its children programmatically by e.g. `component.getChildren().add(...)`. The bean should however be request scoped. A broader scope may lead to inconsitenties as component instances are basically created on a per-request basis and shouldn't be shared across multiple requests. The view scope can also, but this is very memory inefficient, and on Mojarra versions older than 2.1.18, partial state saving must also be turned off, otherwise the view scoped bean instance referenced by `binding` will implicitly be recreated on every request. See also [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense/3343681#3343681) for a related answer.

It's also possible to bind the component to "the view". E.g.

```
<h:someComponent binding="#{some}">
```

This refers to an instance of `UIComponent` in the Facelet scope ("page scope"). This enables you to use for example `#{some.clientId}`, `#{some.value}` elsewhere in the same page. Note that no backing bean is involved here. See also [JSF component binding without bean property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168302/jsf-component-binding-without-bean-property).

Here are some real world use appliances of `binding` attribute:

- [disabling second text field after data validation through ajax of first text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589063/disabling-second-text-field-after-data-validation-through-ajax-of-first-text-fie)
- [Check which form has an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580722/jsf-2-check-which-form-has-an-error)
- [Input text validation based on drop-down list selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263909/input-text-validation-based-on-drop-down-list-selection)
- [How to let validation depend on the pressed button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370675/how-to-let-validation-depend-on-the-pressed-button)
- [How to implement row numbering into h:dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300514/how-to-implement-row-numbering-into-hdatatable)
- [Split java.util.Date over two h:inputText fields representing hour and minute with f:convertDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235721/split-java-util-date-over-two-hinputtext-fields-representing-hour-and-minute-wi/)

Comment: thanks a ton BalusC. I understood your point perfectly. I will read the links provided and get back to you if find any more queries.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC For your explanation. Please  is it possible to bind a UIComponent from a list of UIComponent. e.g List<UIComponent> uicomponents... <ui:repeat value=#{bean.uicomponents} var="c"> <h:outputlabel binding="c"/>

Comment: It seems we may also use `binding` when using `<f:actionListener  binding="#{bean.someMethod()}" />` as an alternative to `<f:actionListener type="com.mkyong.NormalActionListener" />`. Probably not a good idea as BalusC describes, but there you have it.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure it can be entirely avoided, because what if the action listener needs to manipulate some backing bean properties? I guess we could get the bean in the `NormalActionListener` (above comment) using the `FacesContext`.

Comment: @DavidS: `<f:actionListener binding>` (and `<f:validator binding>` and `<f:converter binding>`) aren't "component bindings" as in binding `UIComponent` instances.

Answer (score 2):

read this answer:

[What is the advantages of using binding attribute in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532955/what-is-the-advantages-of-using-binding-attribute-in-jsf)

However, a lot of people in the community do not recommend binding. See this article for example:

http://drewdev.blogspot.com/2009/01/jsf-component-binding-stinks.html

Comment: The author of the blog post has used `binding` for every component after a suggestion from a mailing list and now expresses his frustration with this very bad idea. He thinks that therefore the concept of `binding` is bad and shouldn't be used which is not better than first wrong approach. He suggests that the designers should be killed. It's much better to understand what concepts are for and use them as intended.