# Validation/conversion for two component based composite in JSF

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I'm developing a JSF web application where I need to use periodicities as data structure. Here there are the Java classes I work with:

```java
public class Periodicity implements Serializable {

    private Integer value = 0;

    private PeriodicityType type;

    //Getter and setters

}

public enum PeriodicityType {
    DAY, WEEK, MONTH, YEAR
}
```

That way I can specify different periodicities for my tasks, which can combine values with `PeriodicityType`.

I also have created an input composite element called *periodicityInput.xhtml*, which I can use to provide that data type in different forms in a reusable way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:body>
    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="value" required="true" />
        <composite:attribute name="disabled" required="false" default="false" />
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="#{cc.id}">
            <p:spinner value="#{cc.attrs.value.value}" min="1"
                id="value_spinner" disabled="#{cc.attrs.disabled}" />
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{cc.attrs.value.type}" style="width:200px"
                disabled="#{cc.attrs.disabled}">
                <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true"
                    itemLabel="#{windowsMessages.NOT_ASSIGNED}" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{viewUtils.periodicityTypes}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </composite:implementation>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Basically I have an `spinner` element and a `selectOneMenu`, in order to select a value and a type for the periodicity. There's also the chance not to select any type, **in this case the input numeric value must be zero**. Or, even better, **if no periodicity selected the input must be converted into a null/null tuple**.

As I read in some [sites](http://balusc.blogspot.com.es/2007/12/validator-for-multiple-fields.html) there's the chance to validate multiple JSF components at once accesing the id in the validation method:

> UIInput confirmComponent = (UIInput) component.getAttributes().get("confirm");

Question is, how to adapt it in order to use in a composite component which doesn't have a fixed id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to create a backing component extending `UIInput` and do the job in `UIInput#getSubmittedValue()`. The child inputs are just directly available by `findComponent()`.

```
<cc:interface componentType="inputPeriodicity">
    ...
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    ...
    <p:spinner id="value_spinner" ... />
    <p:selectOneMenu id="type_menu" ... />
    ...
</cc:implementation>
```

with

```
@FacesComponent("inputPeriodicity")
public class InputPeriodicity extends UIInput implements NamingContainer {

    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        return UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getSubmittedValue() {
        UIInput typeMenu = (UIInput) findComponent("type_menu");
        String type = (String) typeMenu.getSubmittedValue();

        if (type == null || type.isEmpty()) {
            UIInput valueSpinner = (UIInput) findComponent("value_spinner");
            valueSpinner.setSubmittedValue("0"); // Don't use int/Integer here!
        }

        return super.getSubmittedValue();
    }

}
```

#### See also:

- [Split java.util.Date over two h:inputText fields representing hour and minute with f:convertDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235721/split-java-util-date-over-two-hinputtext-fields-representing-hour-and-minute-wi)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `<h:panelGrid id="#{cc.id}">` really isn't right. Give it a fixed ID instead if you really need to.