# Two primefaces calendar component validation

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, validation

I've a form in **JSF 2** where I'm using a double field to specify a range of dates. The aim of that is not to let the user to pick a first date which is before the second one. So I want to perform a validation before the form is sent, using `p:calendar` components. What I do is to tie a validator to the second calendar input in order to access the first component internally and compare dates.

Here it is my *xhtml* page:

```xml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head />
<h:body>
    <h:form id="date_form">
        <p:calendar id="date1input" value="#{dateTestBean.date1}" />
        <p:calendar value="#{dateTestBean.date2}" validator="dateValidator">
            <f:attribute name="date1" value="#{date1input}" />
        </p:calendar>
        <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{dateTestBean.submit}"
            ajax="false" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

My managed bean:

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class DateTestBean {

    private Date date1;

    private Date date2;

    public Date getDate1() {
        return date1;
    }

    public void setDate1(Date date1) {
        this.date1 = date1;
    }

    public Date getDate2() {
        return date2;
    }

    public void setDate2(Date date2) {
        this.date2 = date2;
    }

    public void submit() {
        System.out.println("Submited " + date1 + " " + date2);
    }

}
```

My validator class:

```java
@FacesValidator(value = "dateValidator")
public class DateValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        System.out.println(((UIInput) context.getViewRoot().findComponent(
                "date_form:date1input")).getValue());
        UIInput date = (UIInput) component.getAttributes().get("date1");
        System.out.println(date);
        //Will perform date comparison
    }
}
```

The output I get here sending `2013-10-10` as first date and `2013-10-12` as second one is:

> Thu Oct 10 00:00:00 CEST 2013
>
> null
>
> Submited Thu Oct 10 00:00:00 CEST 2013 Sat Oct 12 00:00:00 CEST 2013

Which suggests `f:attribute` tag is not working for `p:calendar` component [as it does for other input components](http://balusc.blogspot.com.es/2007/12/validator-for-multiple-fields.html). However, I can access the first calendar via view root, but enforces me to know the entire path of the client id of the component I want to validate. Both values are set in the managed bean later with no issues.

A workaround would be [to use an ajax call when first date changes](http://qussay.com/2013/07/10/date-range-validation-with-primefaces-calendar/) in order to place it in the model and send it as date itself in the `f:attribute` instead of sending the UIInput (I'm already doing it that way).

Isn't there a better way? Perhaps I have to join them in a single component like in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275847/validation-conversion-for-two-component-based-composite-in-jsf)?

Comment: The `#{date1input}` doesn't refer `id="date1input"`, instead it's supposed to refer `binding="#{date1input}"`. Check those examples more carefully.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date range validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093192/date-range-validation)

Comment: That's true! I haven't seen that, it makes sense because what you're passing is the binded component's reference instead of the id itself. But also enforces you to have it binded, which is IMHO a negative point. Probably the best bet is implementing a double input based component and validating it in one go.

Comment: As to your apparent aversion against using `binding`: carefully read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-binding-attribute-in-jsf-works) how to properly use it. It's indeed evil when misunderstood and misused. As to "best" approach, have you looked at the OmniFaces way in the linked duplicate? No binding, no f:attribute, no other mess. Just a `<o:validateOrder components="startDateId endDateId" />` tag and that's it.

Comment: Many thanks @BalusC, Omnifaces helped me to achieve that. However it seems to break when at least one of the components is null (NPE). My components are not required, I only want to check their order if both of them are not null. It seems not to be specified in the documentation, neither in [validateOrder](http://wiki.omnifaces.googlecode.com/hg/vdldoc/o/validateOrder.html) or [validateAll](http://wiki.omnifaces.googlecode.com/hg/vdldoc/o/validateAll.html). Anyway, thanks for your contribution!

Comment: If you encounter an issue by all means report an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code,

```
<p:calendar id="date1input" ... />
<p:calendar ...>
    <f:attribute name="date1" value="#{date1input}" />
</p:calendar>
```

The `#{date1input}` isn't represented by `id="date1input"`. As shown on those code examples, it's represented by `binding="#{date1input}"`.

Fix it accordingly:

```
<p:calendar binding="#{date1input}" ... />
<p:calendar ...>
    <f:attribute name="date1" value="#{date1input}" />
</p:calendar>
```

#### See also:

- [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-binding-attribute-in-jsf-works)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to set values to null at startup, and on the initial state of the components the second calendar is disabled, and set its `mindate` to the value of the first one.

```
                            <p:calendar
                                id="startdate"
                                value="#{bean.startdate}">
                                <p:ajax
                                    event="dateSelect"
                                    listener="#{origemBean.listener}"
                                    update="@form" />
                            </p:calendar>                   
                            <p:calendar
                                id="enddate"
                                disabled="#{empty bean.startdate}"
                                value="#{bean.enddate}"
                                mindate="#{bean.startdate}">
                                <p:ajax
                                    event="dateSelect"
                                    listener="#{bean.listener}"
                                    update="@form" />
                            </p:calendar>
```

On the managed bean, just verify if the `startdate` is after `enddate` and treat them.