# What method should I override to define my own binding to the backing bean?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, components

I need to create the custom component consisting of 3 input  fields and provide the ability to create a binding the component to a backing bean. I inherited my component clas from the `UIInput`. The issue that I need to convert all three inputs into the `Date` format as follows:

[image]

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
c.add(Calendar.HOUR, 2);
c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 3);
Date d = c.getTime();
```

and set it to the backing bean's property specified with the expression like

`value = #{beanName.beanProperty}`.

What method should I override to do that?

BTW, **[this](http://www.exadel.com/tutorial/jsf/HowToWriteYourOwnJSFComponents.pdf)** article says that we could provide a similar facility in the `Tag` class ever. But there described a value-binding (to a bundle, for instance) which is not exactly what I want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split java.util.Date over two h:inputText fields representing hour and minute with f:convertDateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235721/split-java-util-date-over-two-hinputtext-fields-representing-hour-and-minute-wi)

Answer (score 2):

The article you are referring to is very very old, still working whith JSF 1.0  initial release! you can see that in `faces-config.xml` declarations through the tutoriel:

```
<!DOCTYPE faces-config PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JavaServer Faces Config 1.0//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-facesconfig_1_0.dtd">
```

I think you should absolutly change that tutoriel as there is no need to using JSF 1.0, as from [BalusC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3646940/4170582):

> **JSF 1.0 (March 2004)**
>
> This was the initial release. It was cluttered with bugs in both the
>   core and performance areas you don't want to know about. Your
>   webapplication didn't always work as you'd intuitively expect. You as
>   developer would run hard away crying.

I see that you tagged JSF 2 in your question, you can find a good start for making [composite component](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info) using JSF 2.0 from here (which BTW gives a similar example to the one you provided): [Composite component with multiple input fields](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/01/composite-component-with-multiple-input.html).