# How to make a JSF custom component to store a custom type as its value?

Tags: jsf, type-conversion, custom-component

Seems basic enough...

I have a custom JSF component and its associated renderer. The renderer does the `decode` and `encodeEnd`.

In `decode` i successfully retrie the submitted value via `component.setSubmittedValue(ctx.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get(c.getClientId()));`

In `encodeEnd`, i basically create the markup and if `component.getValue()` is not null, i insert its contents in the markup. So far so good.

Problem is that `getValue()` can be only be `String`. I have custom class that represents a compound data type and i want to use that as the component's local value. But doesn't work - JSF converts to `String`.

I also tried using `component.getAttributes()` - from the `decode` method, where i put my custom object in keyed to `private static final String someKey = "asd"`. But later at `encodeEnd` there is no value/key in the map.

I want the users of this component to be able to specify in their backing bean the custom data type and not worry about serialization/deserialization to text representation between client/server. Presumably i have to use a converter for that? But how can i set up a default and immutable converter for the custom component?

Comment: Although you are not using it, take a look at the source of the PrimeFaces `p:calendar`. It calls converters to/from a `Date` using a dateFormat. I think you can extrapolate that from specifying a class somewhere

Comment: Kukeltje, found it. So it basically overrides getConvertedValue of the renderer itself? Simple enough... Will try it later when I get a chance. It's incredible how the official tutorial - javaee7tutorial will not include that. Thanks for the response.

Comment: It does not include this since it is something that is rarely used by end-users. Of you have a solution or direction, please create an answer and accept it. But maybe there is a duplicate Q/A in https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-m&q=jsf+implicit+converter+getconvertedvalue

Comment: This comes close: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17235721

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has a simple enough of a solution. Inside the Renderer class (or right into the Component class if using that directly):

```
@Override
public Object getConvertedValue(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object submittedValue) throws ConverterException {
    SomeCustomObject thing;
    //... do magic to create SomeCustomObject based on submittedValue
    return thing;
}
```

Now whenever `getValue()` is called on that component, `SomeCustomObject` will be returned and you can safely cast to it. Also in the backing beans can use `SomeCustomObject` as the type.

Also note when calling `component.getValue()` in the actual Renderer, it will return `SomeCustomObject` as well, so if you're restoring state, you must convert back to its String representation.

For more details see and @Kukeltje's answer above and check how the same thing is done for primefaces calendar component here: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/calendar/BaseCalendarRenderer.java

For another more concise and clear illustration, check @BalusC's answer as well.