# Reset inputText after Button Click with JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Is it possible to reset the value of an inputText after clicking on the commandButton in JSF? The inputText UIElement provides the method ResetValue so I tried something like this:

```
<h:inputText  id="measurementadd" binding="#{inputTextMeasurement}">
    <f:validateRegex pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*"/>
    <f:ajax event="keyup" render="measurementaddmessage submit" execute="@this"/>
<h:inputText>
<p:commandButton id="submit" action="#{Bean.addMeasurement(inputTextMeasurement.value)}" 
value="submit" update="dataTable measurementadd measurementaddmessage" 
disabled="#{empty inputTextMeasurement.value or facesContext.validationFailed }" >
    <f:ajax event="mouseup" execute="#{inputTextMeasurement.resetValue()}" />
</p:commandButton>  
<h:messages for="measurementadd" id="measurementaddmessage"/>
```

But after clicking the Button the inputTextMeasurement doesn't reset it's value.

Does someone know a good workaround for this?

I'm searching for a solution without JS and JAVA, so a realization in JSF would be very cool.

Comment: is the binding correct `binding="#{inputTextMeasurement}` and not `binding="#{inputTextMeasurement.value}` ?

Comment: @Kuba: yes, it's definitely correct. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506679/what-is-component-binding-in-jsf-when-it-is-preferred-to-be-used/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mistake is here in the `execute` attribute:

```
<f:ajax event="mouseup" execute="#{inputTextMeasurement.resetValue()}" />
```

The `execute` attribute should represent a space separated collection of client IDs to include in the process/decode of the ajax request. However, you specified a listener method there.

You need the `listener` attribute instead:

```
<f:ajax listener="#{inputTextMeasurement.resetValue()}" />
```

*(and I omitted `event` as it defaults here to `click` which is already the right one)*

Interesting detail is that the other `<f:ajax>` in the same piece of code used the `exeucte` attribute the right way.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, have you looked at [`<p:resetInput>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/resetInput.jsf)? This saves an ajax listener method in the bean. Replace the whole `<f:ajax>` with

```
<p:resetInput target="measurementadd" />
```

Comment: `<f:ajax listener=` doesnt work for me. I am using PrimeFaces 5.3.... Same as in question, I am sending input data to back bean using Binding value. However, after send, I want to delete value on InputText. How is the way?

Comment: `<p:inputText id="newOptionSymbol" binding="#{optionSymbol}" required="false"></p:inputText>
    <p:inputText id="newOptionText" binding="#{optionText}" ></p:inputText>
    <p:commandButton value="Ekle" icon="fa fa-plus color-white" action="#{analysisBean.addOptionToQuestion(analysisBean.question, optionSymbol.value, optionText.value)}" ajax="true" update=":questionEditForm" >
        <f:ajax listener="#{optionSymbol.resetValue()}" />
    </p:commandButton>`

is there a mistake? cuz it should work...

Answer (score 0):

Why dont we just use

```
<input type="Reset"/>
```

This one is works fine for me! ???

Comment: Because this resets the entire form to default values which is not what is been asked here. In case you need that, head to http://stackoverflow.com/q/20077117

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem as below

```
<p:commandButton id="submit" action="#{Bean.addMeasurement(inputTextMeasurement)}">
```

Sending back bean UIInput component. Get and Reset value in back bean.

```
public void addMeasurement(UIInput    
   String msr = (String) inputTextMeasurement.getValue()
   inputTextMeasurement.resetValue();
}
```