# JSF resetting form after submit

Tags: jsf-2

i have a small problem with my jsf form. i made an example registration 
form with a submit button and a reset button:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <title>Register</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <ui:composition template="/templates/master.xhtml" >

        <ui:define name="content">

            <center>
                <h:outputText value="New User Registration" />
            </center>

            <h:form>

                <h:panelGrid columns="3">

                    <h:outputText value="Username:" />
                    <h:inputText id="username" value="#{registerService.userName}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Enter Username!" />
                    <h:message for="username" style="color:red" />

                    <h:outputText value="Password:" />
                    <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{registerService.password}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Enter Password!" />
                    <h:message for="password" style="color:red" />  

                    <h:outputText value="Confirm Password:" />
                    <h:inputSecret id="confirmPassword" value="#{registerService.confirmPassword}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Confirm Password!" />
                    <h:message for="confirmPassword" style="color:red" />   

                    <h:outputText value="Lastname:" />
                    <h:inputText id="lastname" value="#{registerService.lastName}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Enter Lastname!" />
                    <h:message for="lastname" style="color:red" />

                    <h:outputText value="Firstname:" />
                    <h:inputText id="firstname" value="#{registerService.firstName}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Enter Firstname!" />
                    <h:message for="firstname" style="color:red" />

                    <h:outputText value="Date of Birth" />
                    <h:panelGrid columns="3">

                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{registerService.dayOfBirth}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{registerService.days}" />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>

                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{registerService.monthOfBirth}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{registerService.months}" />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>

                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{registerService.yearOfBirth}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{registerService.years}" />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>

                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <h:outputText value="" />

                    <h:outputText value="E-Mail:" />
                    <h:inputText id="email" value="#{registerService.eMail}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Enter E-Mail!" />
                    <h:message for="email" style="color:red" /> 

                    <h:outputText value="Confirm E-Mail:" />
                    <h:inputText id="confirmEmail" value="#{registerService.confirmEMail}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Confirm E-Mail!" />
                    <h:message for="confirmEmail" style="color:red" />  

                    <h:outputText value="Country:" />
                    <h:inputText id="country" value="#{registerService.country}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Enter Country!" />
                    <h:message for="country" style="color:red" />

                    <h:outputText value="Region:" />
                    <h:inputText id="region" value="#{registerService.region}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Enter Region!" />
                    <h:message for="region" style="color:red" />

                    <h:outputText value="Town:" />
                    <h:inputText id="town" value="#{registerService.town}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Enter Town!" />
                    <h:message for="town" style="color:red" />

                    <h:outputText value="ZIP-Code:" />
                    <h:inputText id="zipCode" value="#{registerService.zipCode}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Enter ZIP-Code!" />
                    <h:message for="zipCode" style="color:red" />   

                </h:panelGrid>

                <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Submit" action="#{registerService.addUser}" >
                    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
                </h:commandButton>            
                <h:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset" />

            </h:form>

        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>

</h:body>
```

When i type in something and press the reset button everything is reset (to empty)
again. however when i just type in the username for example and press submit my
error messages are appearing (required messages) as it should be and if i now
press the reset button nothing is reset. everything stays the same.

i want my reset button to work in every state. how can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML `<input type="reset">` element as generated by `<h:commandButton type="reset">` does not **clear** the input values of the form. Instead, it **resets** the input values of the form to their initial values as they are in the initially obtained HTML source code. When you do a `render="@form"`, whereby you basically ajax-update the HTML source code of the entire form, all those input fields will now contain the submitted values in the HTML source code. As evidence that the reset button "works fine", try editing those submitted values once again before pressing the reset button.

You've basically 2 options:

1. Don't use `render="@form"`. Render only explicitly those messages. E.g.

   ```
   <h:message id="m_username" for="username" ... />
   <h:message id="m_password" for="password" ... />
   ...
   <f:ajax ... render="m_username m_password ..." />
   ```

   It's only a hell lot of work to specify them all if you have many of them. If you're using PrimeFaces, [PrimeFaces Selectors](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectors.jsf) may come into rescue.

   ```
   <h:message for="username" styleClass="message" />
   <h:message for="password" styleClass="message" />
   ...
   <p:ajax ... update="@(.message)" />
   ```

   ---
2. Refresh the page by a GET button.

   ```
   <h:button value="Reset" />
   ```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "doesnt work"? Did you remove `execute="@form"` or so? Please elaborate "doesnt work" in developer's perspective instead of enduser's perspective.

Comment: No i didnt remove the execute. when the form is filled out correctly i call registerService.addUser what simply just returns "index.html" to return to my home. it works with execute="@form" render="@form" but not when i just render all my messages

Comment: Your problem is caused elsewhere.

Comment: I would like to do something similar to your #2 but I would like to not use a button because i have a form inside a popup dialog that, if the user hits Cancel, it resets the main form (not the one in which the Cancel button is).  is there a way to do a JS or JSF EL reset button functionality without actually having a button and clicking it ?