# Set value of input field in relation to calendar input

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, binding, calendar

I´m using Primefaces, I have an input field whose value must be generated in relation to an input date, the problem is that the date can be selected by clicking on the calendar or typing, if done in the first way everything works correctly but if done by writing, the value of UIInput in the backing bean is null. I dont know why the binding attribute is not working right or what i´m doing wrong.

```
<p:calendar id="fechaContable"   
                    value="#{movimientoBean.movimientoCab.fechaContable}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"  binding="#{movimientoBean.fecha}" required="true"   
                    requiredMessage="Se necesita fechaContable">  
            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" oncomplete="document.getElementById('anadirForm:numeroAsiento').focus()"/>

</p:calendar>

<p:inputText id="numeroAsiento"   
                      binding="#{movimientoBean.numeroAsiento}" value="#{movimientoBean.movimientoCab.numeroAsiento}" required="false">
        <f:ajax event="focus" render=":anadirForm:numeroAsiento" listener="#{movimientoBean.numAsiento}"/>
</p:inputText>
```

The backing bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MovimientoBean implements Serializable{

......

private transient UIInput numeroAsiento;
private transient UIInput fecha;

......

public void numAsiento(){

.....

try {

        Date date = dateFormat.parse(fecha.getValue().toString());
        fechaContable = sdf.format(date);
    }catch (ParseException e){

    }
}
```

When dateSelect is invoked, the value of UIInput fecha is right, but when the date is written it is null.

Sorry for possible grammar or spelling mistakes

EDIT(Solution):

Here is the code working in case someone needs it, thanks to Laabidi Raissi for his help and the information:

```
<p:calendar id="fechaContable"   
                    value="#{movimientoBean.movimientoCab.fechaContable}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" required="true"   
                    requiredMessage="Se necesita fechaContable">  

            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update=":anadirForm:numeroAsiento" listener="#{movimientoBean.numAsiento}" oncomplete="document.getElementById('anadirForm:numeroAsiento').focus()"/>
            <p:ajax event="change" update=":anadirForm:numeroAsiento" listener="#{movimientoBean.numAsiento}" oncomplete="document.getElementById('anadirForm:numeroAsiento').focus()"/>
</p:calendar>


<p:inputText id="numeroAsiento"   
                       value="#{movimientoBean.movimientoCab.numeroAsiento}" required="false">

</p:inputText>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an ajax event for `change`:

```
<p:ajax event="change" oncomplete="document.getElementById('anadirForm:numeroAsiento').focus()"/>
```

Unrelated to the question, I think mixing `p:ajax` and `f:ajax` is not a very idea.
And also, you shouldn't use `UIComponent`s in managed beans unless you have a good reason.
Refer to [this answer by BalusC for more explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506679/what-is-component-binding-in-jsf-when-it-is-preferred-to-be-used/12512672#12512672)

Comment: Using event="change" i still don´t get the value in bean, only if it is selected by clicking on the calendar but not by typing.

Comment: just a question, it does not work when you click outside (or click tab) the input ?

Comment: If i use `<p:ajax event="focus"` i can´t use render, and if i use `<p:ajax event="focus" update=":anadirForm:numeroAsiento"´ it go into infinite loop. 
I´m using the binding attribute because i haven´t found other way of getting the current value of an input calendar in the backing bean. I accept suggest on how to do it.

Comment: for the calendar binding, you can just create a Date attribute in your managed bean, and have the value of `p:calendar` pointing to it

Comment: Ajax is being executed but the value of fecha is null when it is typed.

Comment: can you remove the binding part, and work with `movimientoBean.movimientoCab.fechaContable` property ?

Comment: Ok i have removed all binding part and is pointing to movimientoBean.movimientoCab.fechaContable, now it´s nearly working, i can get the value when it's typed, but not the first time numeroAsiento is focused, needed to go back and click again on fechaContable, the second time you do it, the value is changed on the bean. Sorry if i don't explain myself right.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, finally it has worked and it wasn`t neccesary to bind.

Comment: You are welcome, sorry for being late, I left yesterday for some work