# How to hide a h:panelGrid

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, hide

I have a `<p:selectOneRadio>` with two `<f:selectItem>` and I have two `<h:panelGrid>`. I want to hide one of the `<h:panelGrid>` depending of the `<f:selectItem>` selected.

```
<p:selectOneRadio>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Hide pnl1" itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Hide pnl2" itemValue="2" />
</p:selectOneRadio>

<h:panelGrid id="pnl1">
    //More stuff here...
</h:panelGrid>

<h:panelGrid id="pnl2">
    //More stuff here...
</h:panelGrid>
```

In this example how can i hide **pnl1** if the option **1** is selected in the radio?

How can i hide **pnl2** if the option **2** is selected in the radio?

Please show me the Bean code needed too.

Only one **pnl** should be showed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it through ajax.

```html
<h:form id="frmPanels">
    <p:selectOneRadio id="sorPanelShow" binding="#{sorPanelShow}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Hide pnl1" itemValue="1" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Hide pnl2" itemValue="2" />
        <p:ajax update="pnlContainer" />
    </p:selectOneRadio>

    <h:panelGroup id="pnlContainer" layout="block">
        <h:panelGrid id="pnl1" rendered="#{sorPanelShow.value eq '2'}">
            //More stuff here...
        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:panelGrid id="pnl2" rendered="#{sorPanelShow.value eq '1'}">
            //More stuff here...
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Note that you have to use a `<h:panelGroup>` to wrap the `<h:panelGrid>` to re-render. This is because each non-rendered `UIComponent` (`rendered="false"`) won't be part of the tree component stored in the view and won't be able to be updated by ajax operations. So, instead rendering each `<h:panelGrid>` on their own, it is better to update the wrapper `UIComponent`. Also, `<h:panelGroup layout="block">` will use a `<div>` when generating the HTML.

Associated info:

- [What is component binding in JSF? When it is preferred to be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12506679/1065197)
- [`<h:panelGroup>`](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_panelGroup.html)

Comment: Hey that was great! but i need to evaluate different, not equal in rendered option, how to do that?

Comment: @KazMiller `rendered` attribute should evaluate to `false` in order to not show the component. So, just provide a field from your managed bean that has a `boolean` value and set its value on the method called by the `<p:ajax>` event.

Comment: where can i see all the expressions that i can use in components with binding?

Comment: @KazMiller it will depend on the available fields from the component.

Comment: Gracias Brother espero tener tu ayuda en el futuro!

Comment: @KazMiller de nada compañero :P