# Hiding div on conditon

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, jsf

Trouble hiding a div once a condition is met. Condition is based off who is logging into a web application.

I have a css file that has the multipleBox div set to visibility: hidden along with other attributes such as border color etc.

Tried to use a function in Ajax. Using DOM properties to change display/visibility of the div depending on who's logging in. No dice.

Also tried to change the div class with javascript. No luck as well.

This function is what I have currently that isn't working how I would like. It is called onload of the body.

function Hidder() {
    var valid = document.getElementById("form1:validate").value;

```
if (valid == true) {

    document.getElementById("multipleBox").style.visibility ="visible";
    }
```

}

No luck in switching between visibiliity or display.

I want it to remain hidden unless the person accessing the web app is an admin. I used jsf tags in my jsp page to retrieve the credential of the user. So the variable valid has a boolean stored in it from the jsp page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide a h:panelGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999818/how-to-hide-a-hpanelgrid)

Comment: @thebrownkid what's wrong with the ID?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694450/how-can-i-show-hide-component-with-jsf

Comment: @thebrownkid: JasperdeVries is right. There is nothing wrong with the client id

Answer (score -1):

I think you `document.getElementById("form1:validate").value` is not how you would access an element by ID.

Try this `document.getElementById("validate").value` assuming 'validate' is the ID of your input field containing the boolean value.

Or use this to get value by form name and field id ="validate"

`document.querySelector("form[name=formname] #validate").value`