# Stuck thread at popComponentFromEL(UIComponent.java:2084) causing high cpu usage

Tags: multithreading, jsf, binding

We are using dynamic binding components on our project.

Getting high CPU usage due to Multiple stuck threads at UIComponent.popComponentFromEL (UIComponent.java:2084)
Every thread refers to the same line number in UIComponent.java at line 2084. Here is the snippet of thread dump.

```
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.popComponentFromEL(UIComponent.java:2084)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2326)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2314)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2314)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2314)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2314)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2314)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.doPostAddProcessing(UIComponentBase.java:1986)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.setParent(UIComponentBase.java:459)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$ChildrenList.add(UIComponentBase.java:2772)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$ChildrenList.add(UIComponentBase.java:2742)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.addComponent(ComponentSupport.java:527)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.addComponentToView(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:354)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.addComponentToView(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:337)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:222)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:135)
javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:96)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:224)
javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:96)
com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:94)
com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:88)
com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:313)
com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:372)
com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:351)
com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:204)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:175)
com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:94)
com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:88)
com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:162)
com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:381)
com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:289)
com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:157)
com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.restoreView(PrettyViewHandler.java:109)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:204)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:133)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:201)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:670)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:137)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I tried the solution provided in below answer but there are many pages in which we have implemented component binding and it is not possible to change the scope of every page.
[Stuck thread at UIComponent.popComponentFromEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093791/stuck-thread-at-uicomponent-popcomponentfromel)
I removed below code from `UIComponent.java` file and it seems to be working.
Here is the [full code file](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.java#L1794)

```
for (UIComponent topComponent = componentELStack.peek();
     topComponent != this;
     topComponent = componentELStack.peek())
{
   topComponent.popComponentFromEL(context);
}
```

Can someone elaborate what is the purpose of  `topComponent.popComponentFromEL(context);`
What is the side effect of that, If I comment that code?

As per JSF form/GitHub issue tracker suggestion, I also add `SERIALIZE_SERVER_STATE` parameter in web.xml but no luck.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.SERIALIZE_SERVER_STATE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Also, try to change JSF version 2.2 still issue is persists

Environment :

1. Mojarra JSF 2.3.2
2. Java 8
3. Primefaces 6.1
4. Tomcat 8.5

Comment: Can you add you explicit Mojarra version? 'JSF 2.3' is just an api version

Comment: the explicit version is JSF 2.3.2 @Kukeltje

Comment: Mojarra, MyFaces or other implementation of JSF 2.3.2 API?

Comment: we are using Mojarra implementation @Selaron

Comment: @BalusC any comment on this?

Comment: @Selaron: Mojarra could already be deducted from the stacktrace... Divyesh: I would expect BalusC (requesting help is not 'appreciated' btw) to not state explicitly whether removal of this code is good or bad. The code is there for a reason, so removal might in situations result in other unclear problems. I would expect him to say what is already stated in the other Q/A to correct the problem: _"Fix the code accordingly that this never happens. Components are inherently request scoped and may absolutely not be shared across multiple requests."_

Comment: @Kukeltje oups :0

Answer (score 3):

> *I removed below code from `UIComponent.java` file and it seems to be working. Here is the code snippet:*
>
> ```
> for (UIComponent topComponent = componentELStack.peek();
>      topComponent != this;
>      topComponent = componentELStack.peek())
> {
>    topComponent.popComponentFromEL(context);
> }
> ```
>
> *Can someone elaborate what is the purpose of  `topComponent.popComponentFromEL(context);` What is the side effect of that, if I remove that code?*

This piece of code basically manages the implicit EL expression `#{component}` in JSF pages. Removing it will affect the behavior of `#{component}` in EL. For example, in the following construct,

```
<h:someComponent id="foo">
    <h:someComponent id="bar" />
    #{component}
</h:someComponent>
```

... the expected behavior is that `#{component}` will give you the one with `id="foo"`. But with your change, it will incorrectly give you the one with `id="bar"`.

---

> *As per JSF form/GitHub issue tracker suggestion, I also add `SERIALIZE_SERVER_STATE` parameter in `web.xml` but no luck.*
>
> ```
> <context-param>
>     <param-name>javax.faces.SERIALIZE_SERVER_STATE</param-name>
>     <param-value>true</param-value>
> </context-param>
> ```

This won't work when you assign component bindings to a `transient` property. Even when you fix that, this still won't really "solve" your problem. It will just throw a `NotSerializableException` at a much sooner moment. Already when you just open the JSF page, instead of that you're facing a "Stuck thread" error when multiple users open the JSF page. The `NotSerializableException` should give a clear warning to the developer that the developer is doing something completely wrong.

---

> *Also, try to change JSF version 2.2 still issue is persists*

The problem you faced is not a JSF version specific problem. It's a developer mistake. Just **never** assign `UIComponent` as a property of a managed bean which is in a broader scope than `@RequestScoped`. See also [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Just do **not** fix the problem by removing the piece of code from `UIComponent.java`. You will still have a non-threadsafe JSF webapplication. When user X modifies one property of a particular component, e.g. `disabled` becomes `true`, then it will affect all other users as well, and this will end up in a non-working webapp.

Comment: Thanks for detailed expiation as we observe `for loop` recursive call and not the break. https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/3827#issuecomment-382248850 what is your view on this fix?

Comment: I disagree that. It's basically hiding a major underlying problem: a non-threadsafe webapp. You should not attempt to fix that by covering/suppressing/hiding all possible exceptions it could cause, no. You should attempt to fix that by its very root problem: just never bind components to a bean which is not in request scope. Then all its possible consequences/exceptions will simply solve by themselves and you end up with a threadsafe webapp. That's what you and your company ultimately want, right?

Comment: there is an alternative of component binding when we use view scope? because when we use request scope there is lots of code refactoring needed.

Comment: Yes. I have explained all alternatives in the "See also" link mentioned in my answer. You do absolutely not need to migrate the scope of all your beans. You only need to migrate all your `binding` usage. More than often, it's not needed at all.

Comment: thanks for your view on this. I will be looking at your solution.

Comment: In long run, I think your approach is correct to do the binding and scope related changes.
When I tried the patch to break the infinite calls, I didn't see any issue in the application. Can you just suggest me steps to be followed to replicate the problem which you are referring to?

Comment: If you're not using `#{component}` anywhere then there's no problem when applying this "patch". But your application is still not threadsafe after applying this "patch". You still need to fix the problem by its root. If you can tell in detail why and how exactly you're using `binding`, then it's for me easier to point out a more specific answer how to correctly replace it.

Comment: sorry for let replay here is the code snippet
https://gist.github.com/geekdiv/229101db5af47f42f3310e16711f0498

Comment: Ahhh .. Just replacing Java by XHTML is the best solution there.

Comment: we have a dynamic form builder how we can achieve it via xhtml?

Comment: Woah, that's a broad question. It's is much easier to answer if you break down your problem in chunks and tell in detail at which step exactly you're stucking. E.g. "How do I loop over a collection in XHTML?" which can be answered as "Use `<c:forEach>` or `<ui:repeat>`". Then we can advance to next step/question. You can always find more elaborate code examples in the link in my answer (and in the links thereof).